# How do i insert a click-able check box into a nstextview?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, nstextattachment

AS the title,now i want to insert a checkbox button into my nstextview,do i need to generate a custom nstextattachmentcell?or sth else?any sample there?
Thx in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you could save a lot of headache by just using a WebView and feed it with some html.

Check WebScriptObject and WebScripting Protocol Reference how to connect the button using JS to an NSObject